# PayPal IPN message not sending invoice, even though it was definitely included in button code

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a paypal checkout button on my website along with funding icons. This is part of the code for it:

```
                 style: {
                    label: 'checkout',
                    fundingicons: true, // optional
                    size: 'responsive', // small | medium | large | responsive
                    shape: 'rect',   // pill | rect
                    color: 'gold'   // gold | blue | silver | black
                },
                payment: function (data, actions) {
                    return actions.payment.create({
                        payment: {
                            transactions: [
                                {
                                    amount: {
                                        total: amount,
                                        currency: currency
                                    },
                                    invoice_number: '{$invoice}',
                                    custom: '{$invoice}'
                                }
                            ],
                            "redirect_urls": {
                                "return_url":  , // these are both filled correctly
                                "cancel_url": 
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

As you can see, the invoice field is explicitly defined, however, when getting sent back IPN messages, my ipn.php file is failing due to the lack of an invoice number being sent to it.

What makes this even weirder is that whenever the txn_type is `express_checkout` the invoice *is* there, but when it's `web_accept`, which is most of the time, neither the invoice nor the `custom` field are getting passed (I added the custom field when the IPN messages started failing).

The api we use for the button is https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js

Is there something I'm missing or is it just that the api is deprecated and this is another sign to switch over?

##### EDIT:

After testing this out on other browsers it seems that adblock is blocking part of the checkout.js dependencies from loading:

- Firefox: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked`
- Opera: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ADBLOCKER`
- Edge: `POST https://www.paypal.com/xoplatform/logger/api/logger net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT`

No error message from chrome.

##### EDIT 2:

sample IPN of type `web_accept`

```
mc_gross=300.00&protection_eligibility=Ineligible&payer_id=SOMEREALID&
            payment_date=11:32:11 Sep 27, 2021 PDT&payment_status=Completed&charset=windows-1252&
            first_name=&mc_fee=9.00&notify_version=3.9&custom=&payer_status=unverified&
            business=our_business_email&quantity=1&
            verify_sign=sign_in_alpha_numeric&
            payer_email=random_alpha_numeric@dcc2.paypal.com&txn_id=1KM93595HU1361254&payment_type=instant&
            last_name=NotProvided&receiver_email=same_as_business_email&payment_fee=&
            shipping_discount=0.00&receiver_id=more_alpha_numeric&insurance_amount=0.00&
            txn_type=web_accept&item_name=&discount=0.00&mc_currency=CAD&item_number=&
            residence_country=OUR_COUNTRY_CODE&receipt_id=1111-1111-1111-1111&shipping_method=Default&
            transaction_subject=&payment_gross=
```

Comment: Are you sure those `web_accept` payments are coming from the above code? Most likely explanation would be they are coming from a standard HTML button or link

Comment: The only place where we use the paypal api which would create ipn messages is here, I don't think there's anywhere else they could come from

Comment: If the IPN listener URL is configured in the PayPal account, any payment the account receives will trigger an IPN message.

Comment: Post an example web_accept IPN you've received (keep any ids but edit out personally identifiable data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example IPN given:

```
mc_gross=300.00&protection_eligibility=Ineligible&payer_id=SOMEREALID&
payment_date=11:32:11 Sep 27, 2021 PDT&payment_status=Completed&charset=windows-1252&
first_name=&mc_fee=9.00&notify_version=3.9&custom=&payer_status=unverified&
business=our_business_email&quantity=1&
verify_sign=sign_in_alpha_numeric&
payer_email=random_alpha_numeric@dcc2.paypal.com&txn_id=1KM93595HU1361254&payment_type=instant&
last_name=NotProvided&receiver_email=same_as_business_email&payment_fee=&
shipping_discount=0.00&receiver_id=more_alpha_numeric&insurance_amount=0.00&
txn_type=web_accept&item_name=&discount=0.00&mc_currency=CAD&item_number=&
residence_country=OUR_COUNTRY_CODE&receipt_id=1111-1111-1111-1111&shipping_method=Default&
transaction_subject=&payment_gross=
```

Note: `@dcc2.paypal.com`

This is from a direct credit card integration, perhaps using the classic NVP DoDirectPayment API, or Virtual Terminal [or Payflow with PayPal as the processor, as it happens]

So, not related to the button code in the question -- rather a separate integration to this PayPal account.

Comment: Ohhhhh interesting. We do have payflow integration, but I was led to believe that payflow does not use any IPN messages. We process these payflow payments with a paybridge.php file and there is no need for the ipn message. Thank you so much!

Comment: Payflow itself does not send IPN messages, but any payment received by the PayPal account will send IPN message to an IPN listener configured in that account (unless the transaction overrides this by specifying a different notify_url)